# Find the measure of the central angle with a radius of $13$ inches and the area of a sector measuring $42.25\pi$ square inches.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm struggling with these types of questions lately. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The area of a sector, radius $r$ angle $\theta$ is $\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$. You know area and $r$, so you can find $\theta$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Three things you might want to know as a user $$$$ 1) [This is to learn som typesetting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 2) The guidelines say "make the title your question", but for good measure it is wise to include it in the main body. 3) Reviewers have a tool dedicated to the removal of "homework questions that do not include any effort towards the solution made by the person asking it".$$$$

Comment: I suspect there may be a typo, and $42.25\pi$ is intended.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that, I changed it. So would the equation look like this? 1/2*42.25^2*13

Answer (score 2):

The area of a circle with radius $r$ is $A = \pi r^2$, and the circumference is $C = 2\pi r$. Suppose we wish to calculate a sector with central angle $\theta$, where $\theta$ is in radians. Because we are using radians, we know that the arc length cut off by the angle $\theta$ is equal to $r \theta$. Now, consider the proportion $A_{\text{circle}} : C_{\text{circle}} :: A_{\text{sector}} : C_{\text{sector}}$, where the "circumference" of the sector is the same as the subtended arc length. We can plug into this ratio to find that 
$$\frac{\pi r^2 }{2 \pi r} = \frac{  A_{\text{sector}}} {r\theta} \implies A_{\text{sector}} = (1/2)\theta r^2$$

This is how we produce the formula given by André. As stated, plug in for everything that you know and try to find the unknown value.

Answer (score 0):

We very well know that the area of a sector having radius $R$ & (aperture) angle $\alpha$ at the center is given as $$\color{blue}{A_{sector}=\frac{1}{2}\alpha R^2}$$ As per your question, radius $R=13$ inch, Area $A=42.25\pi$ square inches, setting the corresponding values we get $$\frac{1}{2}\alpha (13)^2=42.25\pi$$ $$\alpha=\frac{2\times42.25\pi}{169}$$ $$\alpha=\frac{84.5\pi}{169}=0.5 \pi$$$$=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{2}=90^o}$$